# How to create custom wildcard domain in azure

Tags: azure, dns, subdomain, azure-web-app-service, wildcard-subdomain

I'm having an issue with setting a custom wildcard domain on an Azure Website.

The azure website is demo.azurewebsites.net

And my custom domain is tenant1.demo.azurewebsites.net

**I have done following steps : --**

Step A:- Login into the portal.azure.com

Step B:- Then created zone with the following steps.

[image]

In this I filled all required information and select resource group as use existing. Because I have existing resource group. And click on create button.

[image]

C) After click on create button of above image it will show following image.

[image]

D) After that I crated record set. Please refer following image. I filled all information that required.
Name = *

Type = CNAME

TTL = 1

TTL unit = Hours

Alias = my existing domain

[image]

E) after that I created custom domain.

[image]

When I am going to create custom domain it show following error.

[image]

Comment: I really don't understand what you're trying to do there but you can't do that with Microsoft's domain (azurewebsites.net). Use your own custom domain (example.com) and you'll be able to add as many subdomains to it as you please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And my custom domain is tenant1.demo.azurewebsites.net

We can’t add subdomain to azurewebsites.net, because we are not the owner of azurewebsites.net.

> Step B:- Then created zone with the following steps.

Until now, Azure doesn’t provide domain register service.  Azure DNS Zone is used to host the DNS records for a particular domain. Azure DNS Service will answers DNS queries for records in the zone. It works as a name server. The prerequisites to use Azure DNS Zone is that you must be the owner of the domain. Please check the following note from [Azure DNS Zone official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-zones-records).

*You do not have to own a domain name to create a DNS zone with that domain name in Azure DNS. However, you do need to own the domain to configure the Azure DNS name servers as the correct name servers for the domain name with the domain name registrar.*

After you create a DNS Zone, to let the DNS record works, you also need to delegate your domain to Azure DNS by adding name server record in your domain register portal. Though you can add DNS record for demo.azurewebsites.net in your DNS zone as you mentioned in your post. But it won’t work until you have the right to configure the name server record in your domain register portal.